# What is the ちょ in こなしてちょ?

Tags: words, dialects

[image: Screen shot of the game]

I'm playing a video game (Final Fantasy VI), in which a character is reading her lines and stage directions for a play.  The stage directions contain the following sentence:

> この芝居を間奏の間に**こなしてちょ**。

I don't understand `こなしてちょ`.   I think it's the verb `こなす` inflected to `こなし` plus `て`, and then `ちょ` added to that, but I don't know what `ちょ` is.  I think this is some sort of command form.

My question: **what is `ちょ`?**

---

Here are my guesses:

1. `こなしてちょ`　←　`こなしててよ`　←　`こなしていてよ`
2. `こなしてちょ`　←　`こなしてちょうだい`

I think the first is plausible because it's similar to `ちゃ` ← `ては`, and I think the second is plausible because it's similar to the `な` command form shortened from `なさい`.  However, I can't tell if either of my guesses is correct.  (I have a feeling I'm likely to be wrong...)

Sometimes 大辞林 lists colloquial contractions, so I decided to look it up.  There is one [entry for ちょ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=112750100000), but it doesn't seem like the right answer.  It says it attaches to nouns and the roots of adjectives, and this doesn't seem like either of those.  (But maybe `て` can be considered a noun...?)

Comment: I wasn't sure how to tag this question.  If anyone would like to re-tag it with something more appropriate, it would be appreciated :-)

Comment: どこの辞書にも載ってないみたいで・・・http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1462443644　これくらいしか見つけられません

Comment: そ～いえば・・・アラレちゃんって、予告編でいつも最後に「絶対見てちょ。ばいちゃ。」って言ってました。http://jikainoyokoku.blog23.fc2.com/blog-entry-1090.html　ビデオはこれくらいしか・・・http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEAq_L0oeiE&list=PL0BB18D55321C9D33　（←26秒のところ）

Comment: I don't have any evidence right now but I've seen this to mean ちょうだい many times.. is there a reason why people aren't going to that by default?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but quoting the bottom of http://ffdic.wikiwiki.jp/?%A5%B9%A5%C8%A1%BC%A5%EA%A1%BC%2F%A1%DA%A5%AA%A5%DA%A5%E9%A1%DB: "控え室では、コーラスの台本を読むことができるが、
「（この芝居を間奏の間にこなしてちょ。～ダンチョーより。）」なんて砕けた感じで書いてある。[このセリフ](http://ffdic.wikiwiki.jp/?%A5%BB%A5%EA%A5%D5%2F%A1%DA%A5%B4%A5%E1%A5%F3%A4%C1%A4%E3%A1%BC%A4%A4%A1%DB)もこんな雰囲気から出たのかもしれない。". IIRC the 団長 didn't really speak with a 方言, so I'm thinking they might've wanted him to sound cute/child-like here (ちょうだい itself is mainly used by children/women quoting Daijisen, so maybe that was the intended effect(???))

Comment: @cypher Oh, thank you!  That's pretty interesting.  I don't understand "quoting Daijisen", though...  are you saying people only say ちょうだい if they happen to be women or children quoting a particular dictionary?

Comment: @snailboat Yes (or that it's mainly used by women/children, maybe not exclusively). I was quoting Daijisen's definition at http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=12138700: "2.（多く、女性・子供の用いる語）"

Comment: @cypher Hah, I parsed your sentence very poorly.  I thought it was the women/children who were quoting Daijisen ;-)

Answer (score 1):

According to yutaro82さん on [this Chiebukuro post](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1048483265), it sounds like this 「〜ちょ」 could possibly be part of 名古屋弁{なごやべん}.

Looking at [this list of words](http://www.unisys.co.jp/CHUBU/nagoyaben/njun/ta.html) within 名古屋弁{なごやべん} shows that「ちょう」can translate to the standard Japanese word「ください」.

Both of these references don't appear to give an exact reason as to why「ちょう」came to be used to mean「ください」(at least in 名古屋弁{なごやべん},) but your second guess (and in particular,「ちょうだい」) could very well be where this word originated... *though I can't state that with absolute certainty.*

Answer (score 0):

According to [this edit](http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E5%90%8D%E5%8F%A4%E5%B1%8B%E5%BC%81&diff=2721210&oldid=2715704) to the [Wikipedia article on 名古屋弁](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8D%E5%8F%A4%E5%B1%8B%E5%BC%81), `ちょ` seems to be a shortened form of `ちょうせ` (the imperative form of `ちょうす`, which is the 尊敬語 form of `くれる`).