# What is this colloquial / dialect form? 〜たるけんね

Tags: colloquial-language, dialects, contractions

[image: Screen shot]

I'm [still playing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11926/1478) Final Fantasy VI, and I came across this bit of dialogue:

> マリアの頭にオモリ
>   落としたるけんね。

I understand it up to `落とし`.  Orthros is going to drop the weight on her head!  I can't make heads or tails of `たるけんね`, though.  I assume it's some kind of dialect.

My best guess is `落としたるけんね` ← `落としてやるからね`.  Specifically, I think it might involve these two changes:

- `たる` ← `てやる`
- `けん` ← `から`.

Does that seem right?

Comment: Your guesses are right. They're both Western dialect phenomena, although I'm not sure about their exact respective areas. I think けん for から is not used in Kansai, but I know it's used in large parts of 中国地方, 四国 and 九州. たる is often heard in Kansai-ben, but not sure of its use in other western dialects.

Comment: けん is widely used in 九州 but I don't know how often I hear たる...

Comment: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E8%A1%A8 This provides an overview of some aspects of Japanese dialects. Unfortunately I don't see たる in there. But けん seems to be a 中国/四国/九州 thing.

Comment: ~たる [seems to be an 大阪 dialect](http://ja.wikibooks.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%BC%81/%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B) for ~てあげる (or ~てやる, I guess). ~けん is very clearly 九州弁 for me as well. I just have never heard the two in combination.

Comment: けん is not used in 姫路, so it starts west of there. It is used in 広島, so it may start east of there. It starts west of 徳島 (which generally uses something closer to 関西弁), and is definitely used in 愛媛 which means it may start east of there. So basically, it starts west of 関西 and eastern 四国, though I don't know how deep in to 九州 it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ~~たるけんね is Kyushu dialect for ~~てあげるからね(for a desired action) or ~~てやるからな(for a desired or an undesired action; can have a vicious tone). Here I think it's the latter. I don't know if it's Hakata-ben, Kumamoto-ben or another but [this page (博多弁ば教えちゃる！)](http://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/67258/2/) states:

> 博:よかよか！試合中に教えたるけん。
>   （いいよいいよ！試合中に教えてあげるから）

Comment: But the title of that page is 教えちゃる, not 教えたる... hehehe