# Does anyone know what ちゃる means?

Tags: words, verbs, spelling

I have found this sentence `わしがすべて焼き尽くしちゃる`. I know that `焼き尽く` would imply burning something until exhaustion but I don't know what `ちゃる` is.　By chance, is `ちゃる`　just an alternate form of `ちまう` like `ちゃう`?

Comment: This thread (and the comment to the answer) might be of some help... http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/what-is-this-colloquial-dialect-form-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%8b%e3%81%91%e3%82%93%e3%81%ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

しちゃる is a part of Kyusyu dialect. It's same as してあげる。

Comment: I think in the OP's sentence the しちゃる is closer to してやる than してあげる... cos you'd say 「焼き尽くしてやる！」「殺してやる！」 rather than 「焼き尽くしてあげる！」「殺してあげる！」, you know...