# How is たる being used here?

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

I got this sentence from My hero academia anime and I am confused on the usage of したる. The line is said in season 3 episode 9 at the 4 minute 45 second mark.

```
こいつらの方針が変わんねえうちに２～３人ぶっ殺して脱出したる！
```

The english translation is, "Before they change their minds, I'll take down a few of them and escape!"

I came across this post, [Please help me understand this たる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40891/please-help-me-understand-this-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B) , which could maybe seem like the answer to my question but I am not sure. Saying 脱出する seems much more natural here since the character isn't in the act of already escaping yet。

Is don't believe this to be an instance of 足る, being attached to する but I could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This たる is a shorten form of てやる, which means "I'll do ..."

See also:
[What is this colloquial / dialect form? 〜たるけんね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/what-is-this-colloquial-dialect-form-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%8b%e3%81%91%e3%82%93%e3%81%ad)

(Yes, there is the answer already, but I think it's better more simple answer about this たる exists, so I posted.)