# What is the たれ in 「もう一本止めたれ」?

Tags: colloquial-language, dialects, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

In the sentence:

> "もう一本止めたれ" (spoken)

Is the たれ just the "command form" of the たり grammar?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30995/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76509/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11932/9831

Answer (score 3):

The たれ is a contracted pronunciation of てやれ, which consists of the て-form + やれ. So [止]{と}めたれ is a contracted pronunciation of [止]{と}めてやれ. As you can see in these threads:

- [ておく → とく in other contexts; similar 2-kana to 1-kana shortcuts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30995/9831)
- [What is this colloquial / dialect form? 〜たるけんね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11932/9831)
- [How is たる being used here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76509/9831)

～てやる can contract to ～たる. So can its imperative form ～てやれ to ～たれ. This contraction sounds colloquial and dialectal.

The subsidiary verb (～て)やる functions similarly to (～て)あげる, which basically means "do something for someone", but ～てやる sounds more vulgar and less polite, and has another meaning/usage: `To (proactively) perform an action so as to prove one's ability to others.` For more on this, please refer to:

- [what does てやる mean when it is not used for giving?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14413/9831)

Answer (score 0):

That's もう一本止めてやれ
たれorしたれis dialect of somewhere in Japan.

止めてやるmeans I'll (verb)for you.
But てやるis often used when he/she is angry.

I waited but he didn't come. I'll eat them all. 全部食べてやる。(ぜんぶたべてやる)

He didn't come? Eat them all. 全部食べてやれ This is self-talk or suggestion to someone. It sounds angry.